# Pending transactions remain pending forever?

Tags: metamask, pending-transactions, nonce, aave

I have a pending transaction stucked for more than 24 hours. I have receive advice on how to cancel it already so please do not answer me that advice again. Because it hasn't worked for me.

Now my only hope is to know if the pending transaction will be dropped one day or it will remain pending forever? because I cant remove my money from aave until something happens to that transaction, and I have the feeling that nothing will happen until the end of times.

Comment: `I have receive advice on how to cancel it already so please do not answer me that advice again` what advice exactly ?

Comment: @hroussille the advice is to send another transaction in the same nonce. To substitute the original. Supposing that doesn't works, my question is when the transaction, if never mined, is going to be dropped?

Comment: Well it does work, as long as you bump the gas price by at least 10%. As far as I know tx can be dropped under high load ( to free the mempool ). Your tx is pending either because of a too low gas fee or a nonce gap. It may be pending for ever if nodes keep broadcasting it and you never replace it.